# Getting strange tokens (ï»¿) from webservice

Tags: android, http, encoding

I am using Android to send a json-file via http. I am getting a response that looks like this:

```
ï»¿{ "errorcode":0 }
```

Where do the strange tokens in front of the response-json file come from? 
Sending messages to the same service with the same content with an iOS app doesn't return these kinds of tokens.

I have used my implementation of the http-sender-class with two different projects so far and it worked just fine, any ideas why it isn't working in this case?

Comment: Think they are a BOM. Byte Order Mark. Just a guess... Do you specify a utf-8 in your request?

Comment: No, I am not specifying utf-8 in my request. Can I simply remove the first three characters, or does it require a more sophisticated handling?

Comment: Don't know but I do so in such a situation. Just use substring() from indexOf  "{" as then when one day the BOM disappears your code will still work.

Comment: `ï»¿` is the UTF-8 BOM. JSON is encoded in UTF-8 by default (but can also be encoded in UTF-16 or UTF-32). However, [RFC 7159](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159) strictly forbids a BOM from being sent: "Implementations MUST NOT add a byte order mark to the beginning of a JSON text.  In the interests of interoperability, implementations that parse JSON texts MAY ignore the presence of a byte order mark rather than treating it as an error."

Comment: @greenapps: that suggestion would only work once the JSON text has been decoded to Java's native UTF-16 format. If the JSON is received in either UTF-8 or UTF-32, you would have to strip off the BOM from the raw data before then converting it to UTF-16 for processing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for the clarification! Do you happen to know how this is done server-side (just in a few words, so I may get an idea)?

Comment: @deimos1988: how what is done? Stripping of a BOM from a JSON-formatted request, or making sure a server response does not send a BOM?

Comment: He said `server-side` and how to strip it from a response I showed already.